# pushviewcontroller after uiwebview finishes its load

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I am properly pushing `viewController` B from A using `navigationController`. However, I would like to do it once `uiwebview` from `viewController` B finishes its load and not immediately. I tried firstly init B and push A when load ends but with no success, controller is not viewed. How can it be done? thank you.

from controllerA,

```
self.controllerB = [[BViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"BViewController" bundle:nil anUser:self.idUser aLang:self.lang];

//[[self navigationController] pushViewController:controllerB animated:NO]; working if pushed directly here

[self.controllerB view];
```

then, controllerB is initialized, `viewDidLoad` triggered and when `webviewDidFinishLoad`, B must be pushed now or viewed at front.

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView*)theWebView
{
    AViewController *theInstance = [[AViewController alloc] init];
    [theInstance pushBcontroller]; }
```

on `AViewController`,

```
-(void)pushBcontroller{

    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:self.controllerB animated:NO];

}
```

not working...

Comment: Is AVController embedded in the navigation controller? Check that [self navigationController] in the pushBcontroller method is not nil

Comment: Also check and make sure that the web view has it's delegate correctly set to `BViewController` in the nib, otherwise `webViewDidFinishLoad` will never be called.

Comment: @Xono, webviewDidFinishLoad is triggered properly and then also pushBcontroller function is called. Then, nothing happens.

Comment: @rdelmar, that's it, navcontroller is nil! why? any suggestion? Thank you for your comments

Comment: It's hard to say without knowing more about the structure of your app -- it's not clear what AViewController is, and where it fits in to the scheme. Where is your webView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line `AViewController *theInstance = [[AViewController alloc] init];` creates a **new** instance of a `AViewController`.  Since it's **new** it isn't part of the view controller hierarchy and is therefore not connected to the navigation controller.

Give your `BViewController` a reference to the previous controller and use that instead of creating a different one.  Or, perhaps better, send a notification when loading is done that the original `AViewController` uses to know when to change the display.

Comment: I gave an A reference to BViewController and now navigationController is properly set when should pushB. Thanks. However, nothing happens, B is not pushed...